# Calling a function within a function In SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions, sql-server-2014

The below T-SQL code is designed to read ID and check whether ID exists in the Table_1 or not. if it exists, the UDF Getname3 returns a table which consists of all columns of that specific ID, if it doesn't exist I want to call a function called m which is designed to print an Error. But the problem occurs when I want to call m UDF in Getname3. How can i call the m within Getname3 correctly.

Thank you

```
Create function m()
returns nvarchar(max)
as
begin
    return cast('Error happened here.' as int);
end
go

Create Function Getname3(@ID nchar(10))
returns @t Table (Melicode nchar(10), Name nvarchar(50), Id nchar(10), Tel nvarchar(max))
AS
Begin
   if (exists (select * from Table_1 where Melicode = @ID))
   begin
      insert @t
         select *  
         from Table_1 
         where Melicode = @ID
   end
   else
   begin
        dbo.m() // PROBLEM Here
   end

   return
end
go

select *
from dbo.Getname3('0410339127')
```

Comment: You have a bit of a performance issue here. You have created a table valued function but it is a multi statement table valued function. This more often than not is even slower than a scalar function, but you even have one of those inside here.

Comment: You shouldn't have different result sets from one select.  I would handle the existence or non-existence of data in your application layer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't execute a scalar function outside of a valid SQL statement.  Try:

```
SELECT dbo.m()
```

Comment: This would also need to insert into the table variable or the result of the function would be no rows.